# Java Script Function is not Defined JSP Error

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I keep getting "function is not defined" errors while working on a Javascript/HTML page.

EDIT: **Updated Link:** http://jsfiddle.net/Gmyag/134/

EDIT: **Updated link** http://puu.sh/8CxnC/b954c1c803.html is the actual one I'm working with and would likely prove leagues more useful than the fiddle.

HTML:

```
deliveryIdentification is the one giving issues. Code too long.
Had to add code block since I added a jsfiddle.
Sorry for not simplifying the example, but this is the first time I've seen this.
```

If I put everything on a separate script blocks others seem to work, but with the addDelRefOrder() since I need to declare var deliveryDummy[] before it throws "ReferenceError: deliveryDummy is not defined. And if I put deliveryDummy[] in the same block it says "ReferenceError:addDelRefOrder() is not defined".

As to why the structure is so weird it's due to it being a .jsp file. I'm just starting out with JSP and learning a lot along the way.

Any and all help as of how to fix this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a error in your code you want to declare Array like this
var deliveryDummy[];
but proper syntax for declaring array is this 
var deliveryDummy = [];

Comment: Thanks edited this as well and both the puush and the fiddle are updated. Issue not fixed so far.

Comment: One more error, you are using while (list.firstChild) but you never declared list any where in your code.

Comment: Yup caught that a bit ago and updated it. Thanks.

Comment: Changes done to HTML. Issue still unsolved.

Comment: There are 2 html and body tags starting and ending in your html, also one form is outside body tag, which is not proper html syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining *function inside function* ? Here

```
function renderList()
{
    // clean the list:
    while (list.firstChild) {
        list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
    }

    // Recreate li
    for(var i = 0; i < deliveryDummy.length; i++) {
        var entry = document.createElement("li");
        entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(deliveryDummy[i]));
        var removeButton = document.createElement('button');
        removeButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Remove"));
        removeButton.setAttribute('onClick','removeName('+i+')');
        entry.appendChild(removeButton);
        list.appendChild(entry);
    }

    function removeDeliver(deliverIndex){
        deliverDummy.splice(deliverIndex,1);
        // Array changed to re-render List
        renderList();
    }

    function getDeliver() {
    return deliverDummy;
    }
}
```

you have renderList() and inside this two more funcs. This is the wrong structure for Javascript. **Make separate functions**.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. It's been 30 hours awake so far and I'm slipping a bit. I corrected the error in the push and will update the Fiddle shortly.

Comment: Put semicolon ; renderList() after this.

Comment: Done, puush updated as well. Not present in Fiddle must've deleted it at some point.

Comment: Updated it again. Big changes this time around, getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

in your javascript i noticed that you have made calls to functions before you have created them. first fix this issue and see if it resolves your problem.

```
window.onload=function addDelRefOrder()
{
    var deliveryVal = document.getElementById("deliveryIdentification").value;
    // Add to array
    deliveryDummy.push(deliveryVal); 
    // Array changed, Re-Render
    renderList();         /// <==== HERE
}

window.onload=function renderList() // <====== Function created here.
{
    // clean the list:
    while (list.firstChild) {
        list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
    }

    // Recreate li
    for(var i = 0; i < deliveryDummy.length; i++) {
        var entry = document.createElement("li");
        entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(deliveryDummy[i]));
        var removeButton = document.createElement('button');
        removeButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Remove"));
        removeButton.setAttribute('onClick','removeName('+i+')');
        entry.appendChild(removeButton);
        list.appendChild(entry);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you mention one such instance please? I can't spot it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with jsp either but your HTML tagging is a little messy.
Make sure that the html tags are properly nested.